# Javascript How to download image blob data:image/png;base64

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image displayed on my pages that was generated by WaterMarkJs library.

## The Image

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANQKCbAwQIECBAYAABgT5AEQ2BAAECBAgIdHOAAAECBAgMICDQByiiIRAgQIAAAYFuDhAgQIAAgQEEBPoARTQEAgQIECAg0M0BAgQIECAwgIBAH6CIhkCAAAECBA....

## HTML

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBKCbAwQIECBAYAAB...">
```

The above html works just fine when displaying the email how can i make a button that downloads the image?

## my attempt

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVB....">Download</a>
```

> Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added the download attr.

```
<a download="impeach.png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBKCbAwQIECBAYAAB...">Download</a>
```